# Fish Shell Can't use my installed font in wsl

Tags: shell, fonts, fish

I installed Hack fonts but can not use them for fish shell as my font, how can I change my font to Hack ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fish has no influence on the font. It runs inside the terminal and purely communicates with it by sending text (as in strings of characters) back and forth.

The font is purely a rendering thing that you need to configure in your *terminal*. I am assuming the WSL terminal, as a windows application, doesn't read fonts from the linux-side of things, so you might need to install that font as a windows font.

How you then set the font depends on the actul terminal which you haven't described, mostly it'll involve opening up the settings menu and picking it.